# Execute script only if line/text doesn't exists

Tags: linux, bash, sed, terminal

I have below script which will append the file `awslogs.conf` on search of folder names under directory but if I re-execute this script, this appends again. How can I avoid doing this?

```
for NAME in $(ls -1p /home/ec2-user/src/ |grep -v "^_" | grep -v "/$" |cut -d. -f1);
do
sudo tee -a /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf << END
[$NAME]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/airflow/$NAME/*/*/*.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = $NAME
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = CLOUDWATCH_LOGS

END
done
sudo service awslogsd start
sudo systemctl enable awslogsd
```

Comment: You could create an initial file from a backup, and then populate it on every run.

Comment: [you should not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: The obvious answer is - don't re-execute the script. If that's not all you need then you'll have to add some more information to your question telling us what it is you're trying to do and with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The `tee` command by default replaces the content of the file. `-a` overrides that to append instead. If you want to replace the content simply remove `-a` from the command.

If you want to *append* the content only if the file does not already contain it, that's an entirely different proposition. You could for example pull out the contents as a multi-line string and check for the entire thing using GNU `grep`:

```
contents="[$NAME]
datetime_format …"
if ! grep --fixed-strings --null --quiet "$contents" /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf
then
    tee -a …
```